# Entity in Models folder and duplicate class names

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

So I'm pretty new to MVC and Entity Framework.  Upon reading a bit, I found it's typical to put the entity inside the Models folder.  Now, say for instance the entity has a table called Employee.  Now I want to add a model to specify metadata for the Employee table and I want to call it Employee.cs.  However, within the entity.edmx there is already an Employee.cs file and I cannot create the Employee.cs file for my metadata.

Is there another way I should be doing this? Different naming conventions for models or putting the entity in a different place?

Comment: I believe EF generates partial classes. so you should be able to create another partial class with same name

Comment: I do see that, however my question is what to name my .cs file in the models folder where I make more changes to the Employee class.  For instance, I was considering Employee.MetaData.cs or I read to just make a MetaData.cs and include all my metadata. I just don't know what is proper naming convention.

Answer (score 0):

If the metadata should be stored on the DB table just add the properties to the Entity.
If there are calculated or extented properties then you have a **model** and an **entity**. The entity is mapped to a table row.
I usually have my entities prefixed with a letter:
`t_students` for entities, `Student` for models.
Then you can map (maybe even consider AutoMapper) between entity and model.

Answer (score 0):

As Shyju said in the comments, you can use **partial** classes to achieve what you are trying to accomplish.

As an example, you will have your Domain Model, **Employee**.  Then you will have your **MetaData** class for **Employee**.

Both, your Domain Model and MetaData class should go under your Models folder.

Under your .edmx file, your Domain Model should exist, then your MetaData should be a separate class.

So with that said here is what you need to do:

**Domain Model**

```
 public partial class Employee
 {
     public int ID { get; set; }
     public string FirstName { get; set; }
     public string LastName { get; set; }
     public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
     public int Age { get; set; }
 }
```

**MetaData Model/Class**

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

[MetadataType(typeof(MetaDataEmployee))]
public partial class Employee
{

}

public class MetaDataEmployee
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Date of Birth")]
    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Age")]
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Hope this helps!

**UPDATE**

In regards to your response in the comments.. I name my folder `MetaData.cs` and put all of my metadata in there for each separate class.  This makes the separation of concern relatively easy, since you will be able to distinguish between which metadata goes with which class.